# My React app page scroll to Top is ugly. Is there a scroll method that doesn't scroll?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I understand react is a single page app. Is there a scroll method that doesn't scroll the page and is on the top by default? Or what tricks can be used to do that?

```
  useEffect(()=>{ 
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
       // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps  
  },[])
```

More clear :

I visit a page and scroll to bottom. When I go to other page using Link, the visited page scrolled from bottom to top (animated scrolled).

I hope the visited page is on the top by default. Not animated scrolled.

Comment: your question is not clear. @Yusnee

Comment: @lokprakash I improved the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrollTo` function accepts an object with options as well. This way, you can explicitly set the behavior to `instant`.

Also, you should use the `useLayoutEffect` hook to avoid any flickering after the initial render.

Please refer to the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';    

export default Page = (props) => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'instant',
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>Hello World!</div>
    );
};
```

Comment: There is no different. It is still scrolled. Scroll is the problem. I hope its 'Jump" but not scrolled.

Comment: You could try to explicitly set the behavior to `instant`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: AHAAAA!!! This is what I need. Why are you smarter than me about this? You save my time a lot. Thanks. Any way this is the web. I will re-deploy tonight. https://cryptocrazyrich.com

Comment: Glad it worked ;)